# Rails app keeps crashing when experiencing heavy load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, capistrano, puma

I was testing my app as I am anticipating a heavy load next week. I am currently using BlazeMeter to simulate the load. My server is hosted on AWS Elasticbeanstalk and RDS using m5.large EC2 instance. I have set up my application using Puma, Capistrano and Nginx. My config are as below:

```
//nginx.conf

upstream app {
  server unix: ///home/deploy/apps/appname/shared/tmp/sockets/appname-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  root / home / deploy / apps / appname / current / public;

  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
    return 301 https: //$server_name$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 default_server http2;

  root / home / deploy / apps / appname / current / public;

  try_files / system / maintenance.html $uri / index.html $uri $uri.html @app;

  access_log /
    var / log / nginx / access.log main;
  access_log /
    var / log / nginx / healthd / application.log.$year - $month - $day - $hour healthd;
  error_log /
    var / log / nginx / error.log debug;

  location / assets {
    alias /
      var / app / current / public / assets;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache - Control public;
  }

  location~ * \.(jpg | jpeg | gif | css | png | js | ico | svg | svgz) $ {
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache - Control public;
  }

  location @app {
    proxy_pass http: //app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X - Real - IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X - Forwarded - For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X - Forwarded - Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header HTTP_CLIENT_IP $remote_addr;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 / 500. html;
  location / 500. html {}
  error_page 404 / 404. html;
  location / 404. html {}
  error_page 422 / 422. html;
  location / 422. html {}
}
```

```rb
##config/deploy.rb

# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock "3.8.2"

set :application, "appname"
set :repo_url, #"censored"
set :user,            'deploy'
set :puma_threads,    [16, 64]
set :puma_workers,    2

set :pty, true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"#{}"/var/app/current"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

append :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
append :linked_dirs, ".bundle", "tmp", "public/system"#,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/store vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
end
```

There are many tests which failed and the error percentage is high. According to my logs from elasticbeanstalk,

> [error] 2465#0: *2262 testing "/var/app/current/public/assets" existence failed (2: No such file or directory)
>
> [crit] 2465#0: *2216 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream

I am a newbie to this and I have no idea why this is happening! Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

**Update 1:** My website also shows `502 Bad Gateway Nginx` after reaching a certain number of users simulated.

**Update 2:**
Like what Myst has pointed out, I am using a database as well.

```rb
default: &default
    adapter: sqlite3
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000

development:
    <<: *default
    database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
    <<: *default
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
    username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>  
    password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
    host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %> 
    port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>

production:
    <<: *default
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>  
    username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
    password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
    host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %> 
    port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
    pool: 50 #20
    timeout: 10000
```

Versions:
capistrano3-puma (3.1.0)
ruby (2.3.0)
rails (4.2.8)
mysql2 (0.4.9)

Comment: Are you using a database? It's possible that your database is running out of connections, making the 64 thread count meaningless - please review (and add) the database configuration file and the database connection pool count.

Comment: P.S. Rails is often the bottle-neck, not the server, but if the Rails app is fast enough, you could consider a C extension (non-Ruby) app server which might provide better performance (i.e., iodine or agoo). I'm biased towards iodine, since I'm the author.

Comment: @Myst yes I am using a db, I will be adding my config file shortly.

Comment: 1. The `pool` in the database confit should be (at least) equal to the number of threads, or your threads will wait for database connections to become available. Sometimes a higher number is used, I’m not sure why, but either way, at least the same number as the number of threads. 2. After preloading the app, all database connections must be closed, so new connections are opened in the Puma workers. If you don’t know how to do that, set preloading to false.

Answer (score 0):

In general - when dealing with high load at first it's good to measure machine metrics - how much load can it take in terms of RPS/simultaneous clients while being stable. And during this test - LA, memory usage, IO to determine what resource is current bottleneck.

Set upstream connections limit in nginx (`server unix:///... max_conns=20;`), it is unlimited by default and under stress test this may cause workers to swell and get Out-of-memory errors.
Once workers are dead - nginx cannot connect to socket and reports error 502.

See if your `puma_error_log` (it looks that it is confused with access log in config) has exceptions.

Also since you only have 2 cpu cores - I doubt there's need for 64 threads times 2 workers, unless most of your requests result in waiting for calls to an external api.

Comment: `unless most of your requests result in waiting for calls to an external api` - it's very likely that most requests block on the DataBase IO... making the high thread count a possibly correct approach.

Comment: The errors still exist so right now I am trying to play around with the numbers and see which config would improve the situation